# In what situations would I specify operation as unchecked?

Tags: c#, math, unchecked

For example:

```
int value = Int32.MaxValue;

unchecked
{
    value += 1;
}
```

In what ways would this be useful? can you think of any?

Comment: It should be noted that `unchecked` is the default, so it is superfluous, unless you enabled `checked` mode. [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/74b4xzyw.aspx) say: *The `checked` keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

By default, [..] if the expression contains one or more non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `unchecked` when:

- You want to express a constant via overflow (this can be useful when specifying bit patterns)
- You want arithmetic to overflow without causing an error

The latter is useful when computing a hash code - for example, in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) the project is built with checked arithmetic for virtual everything apart from hash code generation. When computing a hash code, it's entirely normal for overflow to occur, and that's fine because we don't really care about the result as a *number* - we just want it as a bit pattern, really.

That's just a particularly common example, but there may well be other times where you're really happy for `MaxValue + 1` to be `MinValue`.